# woocommerce e-mail subject set only once and wont be changed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hello i try to understand the following:

The class WC_My_Email is added over woocommerce_email_classes filter.

```
$emails = wc()->mailer()->emails;
$email = $emails['WC_My_Email'];
for($i = 0; $i< 10; $i++){
    $email->order = wc_get_order(10681); //the order object i need for user mail
    $email->subject = "Mail ".$i;
    $email->trigger();
}
```

In the Mail Class the subject is get by $this->get_subject()

the problem:

i got 10 emails all with subject "Mail 0".

I can change the title over         $email->settings['subject'] =   "Mail ".$i." " but i like to understand why this happens and whats the proper way to do this.

create every time a new Mail Object?

This problem seems only happends to the subject.

thanks